How do i increase clickhouse timeout in Clickhouse
Trying to do massive large inserts, I get exceptions like this:
Code: 159. DB::Exception: Lock timeout exceeded.

I tried to increase timeouts like this, but it doesn't help:
    ClickHouseProperties properties = new ClickHouseProperties();
    properties.setSocketTimeout(6000000);
    properties.setSessionTimeout(6000000L);

How else can I try to do it?

You could change
/etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/lock_timeout.xml
<clickhouse>
 <profiles><default>
 <lock_acquire_timeout>180</lock_acquire_timeout>
 </default></profiles>
</clickhouse>

but usually you still get the same error
Usually locks relates to Ordinary database engine when applying ALTER TABLE
Is this your case?
Check
SHOW CREATE DATABASE your-database
is your database is ordinary
better convert it to Atomic
look details in https://kb.altinity.com/engines/altinity-kb-atomic-database-engine/how-to-convert-ordinary-to-atomic/
